# DaggerHilt Multi Modular Project Cannot access class issue

Tags: android, dagger-hilt, multi-module

I have created a Multi-Modular project in android with dagger implementation. my sub module structure for data module is below.
When ever I try to access method of my `NewsApiInterface` from `NewsDetailsImpl` inside testRepo() method and on compile time I get the error

> Cannot access class 'retrofit2.Response'. Check your module classpath
> for missing or conflicting dependencies

**Module:**

> ```
>  data (Module)
>    repository (Implementation Module)
>    network(API Service Module)
>    cache (Database Module)
> ```

**repository Module -> datasource**

```
class NewsDetailsImpl @Inject constructor(
        val db: NewsDatabase,
        val service: NewsApiInterface
    ) : NewsDetailsRepository {
    override suspend fun fetchNewsDetail(): Flow<News>  = flow{

    }

    override suspend fun fetchNewsList(
        query: String,
        limitStart: String,
        limitEnd: String
    ): Flow<List<News>>  = flow {


    }

    fun testRepo(query: String){
        val news = service.getNews(query)
    }
}
```

**repository module -> di**

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class RepositoryModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideNewsRepository( db: NewsDatabase,
                               service: NewsApiInterface
    ): NewsDetailsRepository {
        return NewsDetailsImpl(db,service)
    }
}
```

**data module -> network module -> di**

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object NetworkModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesNewsService() : NewsApiInterface {
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(
                OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor { chain ->
                        val url = chain
                            .request()
                            .url
                            .newBuilder()
                            .addQueryParameter("apiKey", NetworkConstants.API_KEY)
                            .build()
                        chain.proceed(chain.request().newBuilder().url(url).build())
                    }
                    .build()
            )
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .build()
        return retrofit.create(NewsApiInterface::class.java)
    }

}
```

**data module -> network module**

```
interface NewsApiInterface {
    @GET("everything")
    public fun getNews(@Query("q") query: String): Response<NewsDto>
}
```

Comment: Hi have you fixied this?